# objective-c regex to remove NSString characters if they start with spaces and commas

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

My app uses addresses. I am not sure how to create a regex that strips away an address that reads like these.

```
"  ,  Paxton, TX"
"    ,  Dallas TX"
```

Need the above to be stripped so they read like this.

```
"Paxton, TX"
"Dallas TX"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `NSString` API `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`

```
NSString *test = @"  ,  Paxton, TX";
NSMutableCharacterSet *charset = [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] mutableCopy];
[charset addCharactersInString:@","];

NSString *final = [test stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charset];
NSLog(@"final = [%@]",final);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this without using regular expressions

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ,"];
NSString *trimmed = [@"  ,  Payton, TX" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSet];
NSLog(@"%@", trimmed); //prints "Payton, TX"
```